# ng-click and ng-class to toggle classes

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to accomplish toggling `open` class to `nav` element with button click.
Below code does not assign `open` class to `nav` neither removing `open` when button is unclicked.

```
<nav class="slide-menu" ng-class="{'open': open, '': !open}">

<button class="slide-btn" ng-click="open=!open"></button>
```

I'm aware `''` this is obviously wrong as it just assigns literal as class.

Comment: try `ng-class="{'open': open}"`, We don't need to `'': !open`

Comment: I tried that initially, doesn't work..

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/WgJmz/1/

Comment: I omitted `'': !open` but still not adding `open` class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding an `ng-init` to a container div:

```
<div ng-init="open=false">
    <nav class="slide-menu" ng-class="{'open': open}">
    <button class="slide-btn" ng-click="open=!open"></button>
</div>
```

Or add `$scope.open = false;` in your scope.

What happens in your above code is that each one of the two elements has it own scope, which contains a `open` property, so you can wrap them in another element (that has it's own scope) and place the `open` property there. so in the inner scopes of the `nav` and the `button` when it tries to look for a property called `open` it looks in it's own scope and don't find it, so it looks in it's parent scope (the wrapping div) and find it there.

You can understand more about angular scope inheritance from here:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

-- Also, you don't need the `'': !open` part.